# Obtain all rows, and only show one

Tags: php, mysql

I connect to database and all is correct, I do the select and all is correct. But the problem comes when I tried to obtain all the rows. I tried with all mysql_fetch... (array, assoc...)

```
$registros = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM  22bf654e4dfa688d0ec6add2f6f7bf76", $con);
$reg = mysql_fetch_array($registros);

if( ($reg)
{
    echo $reg;

}
```

Comment: I'd suggest a [basic MySQL/PHP tutorial](http://devzone.zend.com/12/php-101-part-8-databases-and-other-animals_part-1/).

Comment: hahaahah xD yeah the table is that name.. i know is weird but is a table create automatically for each user... I tried with that you put Joachim, but it doesn't work

Comment: 1 table per user? that sounds like a really bad idea

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Keep in mind `mysql_` library is deprecated and you should be using PDO or MySQLi.**

Using PDO your code would look like this:

```
<?php
// Your database info
$db_host = '';
$db_user = '';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = '';

$con = new PDO("mysql:host={$db_host};dbname={$db_name}", $db_user, $db_pass);
$con->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

$sql = "SELECT * FROM  22bf654e4dfa688d0ec6add2f6f7bf76";
$result = $con->prepare($sql);
$result->execute();

$reg = $result->fetchALL(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$con = NULL;        
print_r($reg);
// To show just one row you can use:
print_r($reg[0]);
// So let's say you have a field called "name", then u could use:
echo $reg[0]['name'];
```

---

You need to iterate over the results, this will store all the data into an array `$reg`:

```
<?php
// your database info here
$db_host = '';
$db_user = '';
$db_pass = '';
$db_name = '';

$conn = mysql_connect($db_host, $db_user, $db_pass);    
if (!$conn)
{
    die("Unable to connect to DB: " . mysql_error());
}

if (!mysql_select_db($db_name))
{
    die("Unable to select {$db_name}: " . mysql_error());
}

$sql = "SELECT * FROM  22bf654e4dfa688d0ec6add2f6f7bf76";    
$registros = mysql_query($sql);
if (!$registros)
{
    die("Error: " . mysql_error());
}
$reg = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($registros))
{
    $reg[] = $row;
}

print_r($reg);
// To show just one row you can use:
print_r($reg[0]);
// So let's say you have a field called "name", then u could use:
echo $reg[0]['name'];
```

Comment: got to think '22bf654e4dfa688d0ec6add2f6f7bf76' is not the table name, but a row id?

Comment: @Dagon the application will die and tell him the error which hopefully he will tell us so we can point him on the right direction.

Comment: application murder is a sin

Comment: @Dagon god shall forgive us.

Comment: a lot of thanks Prix, nice comment I only change 
while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($registros)) and works... I lost my mind try it... One question...This is the same that you said Prix? (before it doesnt work but with your code, yes) $row = mysql_fetch_assoc($registros);       while ($row)
{
    $reg[] = $row;
}

Comment: [Glad its working for you, **don't forget to mark this answer as accepted**, see here how.](http://stackoverflow.com/about) No they are different in execution.

Comment: Done Prix, that is the reason my way doesn't work

Comment: The $row outside the loop does not iterate.

Answer (score 1):

You should be using `mysqli` instead of `mysql`, but that's a whole other answer.

```
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    echo $row['column-name-here'];
}
```

That will loop through ALL results from your query.  If you only have 1 result, it will only show 1.  If you only WANT 1 result, then specify in your query to which you want like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE something = something;
```

Answer (score 0):

$reg is an array of all rows; you want to use foreach to iterate through it and then print_r instead of echo on each iteration because that will be an array of columns for that row

If you only want the first row,
`print_r($reg[0])`

But better yet use a where clause in your query or a limit statement for better performance. Don't return more data than you need.